# JSF2 ajax call after page load

Tags: ajax, jsf-2

We are JSF2 in weblogic10.3.7.

We have requirement to make auto trigger the ajax call after the page load is completed.

Probably this can be triggered from javascript document.ready function.

Any better ways ?

Thanks

Comment: Your trigger fire one or more time ?

Comment: I mean your trigger call like pool or call one time like button.

Comment: I had a similar need and fixed it by using the following:

<p:remoteCommand name="updateHeader" update="fieldId" autoRun="true"/>

Pay special attention to autoRun!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at PrimeFaces's [RemoteCommand](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/remoteCommand.xhtml). You can call this `RemoteCommand` in your `document.ready` function to execute some bean method.

Comment: We don't have prime faces library in our application.

Comment: Is there a requirement where you absolutely cannot use any 3rd party libraries? :S

Comment: We tried to avoid third party libraries as much as possible

Answer (score 0):

Try following code which does not include any external library.

xhtml code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var startCalls=false;
        $(document).ready(function (){
            clickButton();
            startCalls=true;            
        })
        function clickButton(){
            document.getElementById('btn_test').click();
        }
    </script>
    <h:commandButton id="btn_test" value="Test"
                     actionListener="#{testBean.increaseCount}"
                     style="display: none">
        <f:ajax execute="btn_test" render="pnl_update_area"/>

    </h:commandButton>
    <h:panelGroup id="pnl_update_area">
        This is called #{testBean.clickCount} times
        <script type="text/javascript">
            if(startCalls){

                setTimeout('clickButton()',200);                
            }
        </script>
    </h:panelGroup>
```

JSF Code:

```
Integer clickCount=1;

public Integer getClickCount() {
    return clickCount;
}

public void setClickCount(Integer clickCount) {
    this.clickCount = clickCount;
}

public void increaseCount(ActionEvent event) {
    clickCount++;
}
```